# Python taking statistics over each latitudes and longitudes pair

Tags: python, pandas

I have a year's worth of data and this is just a sample of how it is formatted:
[sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KssjM.png)

for each lat and lon pair I need to take statistics over a  time period. How do I do this???

For example:
there are 1000s of temperature values specifically at lat = 25.313 and lon = -108.813. This data is mapped on a grid of the US and at each particular lat and lon I want to take statistic on based on time for temperature. I have not done something like this before and I need to figure out a method to do this.

I have not utilized data before where it was represented like this I am going to search the web to see how to do this. More or less this is for some sort of advice since my inital results seem to be lacking.

Thanks!

Edit I noticed a way to get each data point at a particular time step, hourly, so I horizontally reorganized the variable in particularly I wanted. All I need to do now is to run my averages across each row.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
finaldf = pd.DataFrame()
directory = "C:/Users/truet/OneDrive/Desktop/test"  #change last directory

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    fullpath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath) and fullpath.endswith(".csv"):
        dfchild = pd.read_csv(fullpath,usecols=[4])
        #define columns you want to explort
        dfmaster = dfchild

        finaldf = pd.concat([finaldf, dfmaster],axis = 1)
    print(dfmaster.reset_index(drop=True))
    finaldf.to_csv("C:/Users/truet/OneDrive/Desktop/test.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: What do you specifically want to do. What statistics. Do you know how to code? How big is your data?

Comment: I want to  take the mean then write a script for standard deviation. I know how to code and the data is 50gbs in size. I used Pandas before but  I haven't utilized a large dataset before. lat is between (25.063 and 52.938 w0.125 step) lon btwn (-124.938 & -67.688 w0.125 step).  All data is represented in those 4 columns. Time span from 1/2019 to 1/2020 recorded hourly.  I want to do this so I can then use geospatial python package to map these values with a color map

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html that will do all sorts of aggregation. For any data manipulation that requires you to loop over the data using Python, things will be very slow in view of the size of the data. A better option would be to use Julia programming language that has a speed close to C without the difficulty of C. Please tell me if you got things going, otherwise, show some sample data and I will give you a hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty broad question since you could be doing anything with your data, but in general you'll probably want to make use of the `groupby` method, where you can group your table into chunks and apply the same statistical method to each group.

```
import pandas as pd

# read in your data from whatever form (e.g. csv file)
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# group the data by each lat-lon pair:
df_groups = df.groupby(['lat', 'lon'])

# apply a method of your choice:
df_groups.sum()
df_groups.count()
df_groups.mean()
df_groups.std()

# or apply a user-defined function
df_groups.agg(lambda x: x*5 / 100)
```

Comment: Hey I just updated my question recently. That could actually work too!! Awesome-- Could this theoretically work on a row to row basis? there are 103936 rows and each row is my theoretical group now---

Comment: Hey yes of course you can apply this to rows as well; you just eliminate the groupby function and apply functions to the data frame directly.

Comment: Ah yeah df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)
df['std'] = df.std(axis=1)