# Python using pandas to take average of same lon/lat value pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average, geospatial

I am using an extremely large dataset with around 1.6 million individual entries for the timespan I am trying to observe (1948 - 1960). An example of my dataset loaded into pandas before attempting to be averaged looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2QXb.png).

```
import pandas as pd
import pyreadr

data = pyreadr.read_r('C:/fileLocation/file.rds')
df = data[None]
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df = df['1948':'1960']
print(df.info())

df_groups = df.groupby(['lat', 'lon'])['spei'].mean()
print(df_groups.head())
```

Now the answer I [get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmDEl.png)

An example input/output could look like as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsNps.png)

What I am trying to accomplish is to take pairs of latitude and longitude values, and take the average spei value of each pair, then create a new pandas data frame with those new pairs and the spei value attached with that pair to be plotted later. Instead, I am getting only 5 rows of seemingly random latitude and longitude values, instead of each unique pairs with average spei from all repeating lon/lat values. I've used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64923290/python-taking-statistics-over-each-latitudes-and-longitudes-pair) to try and help get some answers but I have not been able to find a fix yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please don't take screenshots of your code, input/output data or errors. Instead you should include it in your question as text. That way it is easier for people to work with it. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue:

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample dataframe
data = {
    'lat': [40.0, 40.0, 41.0, 41.0, 42.0, 42.0],
    'lon': [-105.0, -106.0, -105.0, -106.0, -105.0, -106.0],
    'spei': [-1.2, -0.8, -0.5, -1.1, -1.3, -0.9]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# group by pairs of latitude and longitude and calculate the mean spei value for each pair
df_groups = df.groupby([df['lat'], df['lon']])['spei'].mean().reset_index()
df_groups.columns = ['lat', 'lon', 'spei_mean']

# print the resulting dataframe
print(df_groups)
```

which returns:

```
    lat    lon  spei_mean
0  40.0 -106.0       -0.8
1  40.0 -105.0       -1.2
2  41.0 -106.0       -1.1
3  41.0 -105.0       -0.5
4  42.0 -106.0       -0.9
5  42.0 -105.0       -1.3
```